# How to turn on the flashlight (from Torch package) when taking a picture, in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, lamp, torch

I am making an app that can be used to take photos. I would like the flash to always be on. I know that there is no package that directly affects the camera flash. As an alternative I use the Torch package that turns on the 'normal' flashlight. I turn on the light for a second. However: The light does not turn on after you press the 'take photo' button, but already when you open the camera.

Current:

- Click on the button that opens the camera
- Flash goes on for a second
- The photo has yet to be taken

Wanted:

- Click on the button that opens the camera
- Click on the button with which you take a photo
- The flashlight turns on for a second, and at the same time:
- The photo is taken, with a half second delay, so that the photo is exactly in the middle of the flashlight duration

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? I can find few useful examples on this topic

Current Dart code:

```
  takePicture() async {
    Torch.turnOn();
    Torch.flash(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    File img = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    if (img != null) {
      image = img;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer to delay taking photo for half a second after Torch.flash:

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 450), () {
    File img = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera); });
```